# Prove $f(x) =0$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]→\Bbb R$ be continuous with $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Suppose that for every $x ∈ (0,1)$ there exists $δ > 0$ such that both $x−δ$ and $x+δ$ belong to $(0,1)$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x−δ)+f(x+δ))$ . Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$.

I have considered several approaches but not had much success with any of them. First, I tried to prove that $f'(x)=0$ for all x, because as we're given $f(0)=f(1)=0$, I think that is sufficient? But I ran into trouble proving that the limit exists for some general $a$ in the domain. So I decided to try and use continuity, specifically around zero: my intuition was that for $x$ sufficiently close to 0, $f(x)$ is approximately zero and I tried to build up that the images of the two perturbations would also be zero but again without much success.

Please could I have some help? Ideally, a discussion of the right kind of intuition as well as a sketch solution. Comments on whether my approaches were at all in the right direction would also be appreciated.

Edit: Please could this be solved with using connectedness and compactness.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suppose $f$ has a nonzero extreme value and start looking at what happens in that vicinity

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Assume $f$ is not identically zero. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, so is its image under $f$, so there's a numerically largest value of $f$ in $[0,1]$. Furthermore, there must be a *smallest* $x$ such the $|f(x)|$ has this largest value. Plug this $x$ into the property you're assuming and derive a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't yet know the definitions of compactness and connectedness, and I would like to try to solve this without. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @JohnSmith: There's no use of connectedness at all in this hint. Do you have the theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval has a global (but not necessarily strict) maximum?

Comment: Ahh, I've just seen both those concepts being used together very often, so I was explaining I wasn't familiar with either. I'm aware your suggestion didn't use connectedness.

Comment: And yes, I know the Extreme Value Theorem - since this domain is bounded, $f$ is bounded and attains its bounds?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes, and that is all I use here -- though it is not enough that the domain is _bounded_; it also has to be _closed_. For example, $(0,1)$ is bounded, but $f(x)=1/x$ is not bounded on this domain.

Comment: Ahh, silly me, thank you. I'll have a think on your hint now.

Comment: Let $s=sup(f(x):x\in[0,1])$. Then $\forall \delta>0,\space f(s)\ge f(s-\delta)$, and $f(s)\ge f(s+\delta)$. Since $\exists \delta_1$ such that $f(s)=\frac{1}{2}(f(s+\delta_1)+f(s-\delta_1),\space f(s)=f(s-\delta_1)=f(s+\delta_1)$. But then we can find $\delta_2$ such that $f(s-\delta_1-\delta_2)=f(s-\delta_1)=f(s)$ by repeating the process for $f(s-\delta_1)$. So we can find a sequence $(\delta_n)$ such that $\lim_{N \to \infty} f(s-\sum_{n=1}^N\delta_n)=f(s)$. But this contradicts continuity of f, since $\forall\epsilon>0 \space\exists \eta>0$ such that if $|x|<\eta$ then $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Is the above correct please, @HenningMakholm ?

Comment: @JohnSmith: At the very least, you're misusing the symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$ horribly when you're apparently using them as shorthand for the English words "for all" and "there exists" instead of as part of complete logical formulas. When you're writing MathJax there are not even any keypresses saved by writing `$\forall$` instead of typing out the English words in full, so what do you hope to gain by this abuse of symbolism -- other than needlessly obfuscating your argument?

Comment: As for the substance, it will be much easier simply to set $x_0=\inf\{x\mid f(x)=s\}$ and argue by continuity that then you get $f(x_0)=s$.

Comment: Ah, you appear to think $s$ is an $x$ -- but your notation $\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in[0,1]\}$ defines $s$ to be an $f(x)$.

Comment: Because the title of this question was edited by an experienced StackExchange user, who changed my words "for all" to the symbol "$\forall$". This didn't save time or effort, but I deferred to what I thought was the a combination of mathematical expertise and StackExchange convention. Moreover, I've seen many many questions and answers, some by clearly very successful and experienced users, who break this exact rule. It is important for mathematicians to be precise and accurate in their use of language, but I feel your reaction is slightly disproportionate.

Comment: Ahh thank you, a small typo - I'll correct it.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Well, shame on them, then. I'll edit back.

Comment: I can't actually edit my previous comments of 20 minutes ago - but change the very first "$s$" to an "$f(s)$" and that solves that issue, I think?